# VBA - Change Formula dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

I have an drop-down validating formuala for a cell and am using the generic formula inside the validation in vba.

Now, I want to automate it using the formula1 part inside the with loop here.

Here goes the Code,

```
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow2 = Sheets("Config").Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        With Range("M" & i).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Config!R2:R10"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
        End With
    Next
```

how would you replace the part in the code - Formula1:="=Config!R2:R10" with the 10 being Lastrow2.

Thanks

Comment: Formula1:="=Config!R2:R"&Lastrow2

Comment: @Xire or Sid29, please post as an answer so this post can be marked as complete so it does not sit in the open-state indefinitely.

Comment: Xire's answer worked. So, if Xire can put that in the answer section, I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution :

```
Formula1:="=Config!R2:R"&Lastrow2
```